# How to show i hidden div field when i click on a submit and same time call servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I created a jsp (upload.jsp) page to upload a file. When i click submit, it will call servlet and read the file content. Another jsp page (Say filecontent.jsp) is used to display the content. I am using `<iframe>` in upload.jsp to insert filecontent.jsp. And it is hidden. What i actually want is when i click upload, it should call servlet and then display the iframe in same page so i can display file contents.

This is my jsp page.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="regist" action="Registration" onsubmit="return validateFile(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data"
            method="post">

            <div class="control-group" class="span12">
                <label class="control-label" for="file">Please upload a
                    file:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="file" name="file"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="showFrames" class="hidden">
<iframe src="filecontent.jsp" width="700" height="800"></iframe>
</div>
```

And this is my script.

```
<script>
function validateFile(form) {
    var fileName = form.file.value;
    if (!fileName) {
        alert("No File Selected!!!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#showFrames").show();

    }
}
</script>
```

But it is not working. When I click upload, it doesn't show the frame.
What is the error and what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the response of the `Registration` request in the iframe you have to set that iframe as the form's target:

`<form target="myframe" ...>` and `<iframe src="filecontent.jsp" name="myframe ...>`

Comment: thank you. But what if i want to display more than one i frames?

Comment: One response in many iframes? Or the response of the first request in iframe 1, the response of the second in iframe 2 etc.? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a jQuery selector? Is jQuery loaded?

If your class .hidden { display: none; } contains you can use VanillaJS like this:

```
function validateFile( form )
{
    var fileName = form.file.value;

    if (!fileName)
    {
        alert("No File Selected!!!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById( "showFrames" ).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```